# Chrome Remote Desktop only works when I am logged-in

Tags: remote-desktop, 19.10

I have installed Chrome Remote Desktop (CRD) in Ubuntu 19.10 and it works when I am logged-in (browse to https://remotedesktop.google.com/access/session/c16c5d53-4824-aac2-6117-ba3170fba2d4 -> click the Ubuntu device -> enter PIN -> desktop is displayed). When I log out of my Ubuntu desktop, CRD shows the device online, but never prompts me to enter a PIN. Eventually, CRD says that my device is offline (the icon is still green, though).

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is by design. If you want to login remotely, consider x11vnc or xrdp. I prefer x11vnc as it allows remote access whether you are locally logged in or not.

Comment: That is disappointing. Google's solution is so simple.

Comment: I think the Chrome remote desktop "server" is only on if you are logged in. I have not used it for some time. I thought the PIN changes every time you open the page in Chrome.